# Weather Underground API Astronomy

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the Weather Underground API, parsing Json, and getting a result.
For some reason this is not working to get the right astronomy results like so:

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/astronomy&MR=1

Moon:

Current:

Sunrise:

Sunset:

Here is what I have so far and am getting no results:(updated)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/72df18b7f213607b/astronomy/q/CO/Alamosa.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var hourly = parsed_json['moon_phase']['current_time']['sunrise']['sunset'];

        for (index in hourly) {
            var newHourlyString = moon_phase[index]['hour'] + ' is ' + current_time[index]['hour'];
            var newHourlyParagraph = $('<p/>').text(newHourlyString);
            $(".astro").append(newHourlyParagraph);
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: What is this line ` var astronomy = parsed_json['moon_phase']['current_time']['sunrise']['sunset'];` suppose to do?

Comment: I am trying to set a variable to an array of objects to parse I think.

Comment: any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "You think"? You're not going to get very far without knowing where you're going.

Comment: This is the error I am getting https://unsee.cc/notabemu/

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6A138NBuyk&feature=youtu.be at time 3:30 for the Hourly 1-day Forecast

Comment: Where are the moon_phase & current_time objects vars declared? This code is not complete.

Comment: I am not sure. I am pulling in the info from the api url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. There was a lot missing from your question but I was able to pull info from the video you linked.

You should also work on [asking better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all necessary details included to get better answers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/72df18b7f213607b/astronomy/q/CO/Alamosa.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(parsed_json) {
      var moon_phase = parsed_json['moon_phase'];
      var moonData = {};
      moonData['Moon Ill'] = moon_phase['percentIlluminated'] + '%',
        moonData['Moon Age'] = moon_phase['ageOfMoon'],
        moonData['Current Time'] = moon_phase['current_time']['hour'] + ":" + moon_phase['current_time']['minute'],
        moonData['Sunrise'] = moon_phase['sunrise']['hour'] + ":" + moon_phase['sunrise']['minute'],
        moonData['Sunset'] = moon_phase['sunset']['hour'] + ":" + moon_phase['sunset']['minute'];

      for (index in moonData) {
        if (moonData.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          var newHourlyString = index + ': ' + moonData[index];
          var newHourlyParagraph = $('<p/>').text(newHourlyString);
          $(".astro").append(newHourlyParagraph);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="astro"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realize I had to first set the var to an object and then break out the object. Could you look at this last one if you do not mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143350/weather-underground-hourly-1-day-forecast/28143750?noredirect=1#comment44659947_28143750

Comment: Its a simililar problem that you should be able to work through especially after the hint provided. inspect the `FCTTIME` object in each and pull out the necessary info.